# Why does my Keras LSTM model not learn patterns on the training set and even gets worse over time?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to fit a sequential model (LSTM) to my data. For this I am using the Keras library.

Simplified, my target is a counter that counts people every day in a location. The features are weather data, public holidays and the current date. In total there are 21 features.

My goal is to take the last 3 days, and the data of the next day (4 days in total) including weather prediction, to forecast the number of people for that day.

For comparison I have a base line error which is ~10000 and I fitted already two models which are xgboost with a training error of ~5000 and a dense model with a training error of ~7000. The absolute values are not important but I just mention them, so you get a feeling and to state, that other models are indeed capable of picking up the patterns.

My input shape is:

```
X_train_3d.shape
>>> (2918, 4, 21)
```

The first element looks like this:

```
X_train_3d[0]
>>> array([[2.0130e+03, 1.0000e+00, 1.0000e+00, 1.0000e+00, 9.1000e+00,
        6.9000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 1.9400e+01, 1.0018e+03, 0.0000e+00,
        1.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,
        1.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,
        0.0000e+00],
       [2.0130e+03, 1.0000e+00, 2.0000e+00, 2.0000e+00, 7.1000e+00,
        1.8000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 2.0200e+01, 1.0175e+03, 3.0000e+01,
        1.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,
        0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,
        0.0000e+00],
       [2.0130e+03, 1.0000e+00, 3.0000e+00, 3.0000e+00, 1.0600e+01,
        9.0000e-01, 0.0000e+00, 2.3800e+01, 1.0245e+03, 0.0000e+00,
        1.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,
        0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,
        0.0000e+00],
       [2.0130e+03, 1.0000e+00, 4.0000e+00, 4.0000e+00, 9.7000e+00,
        0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 2.5200e+01, 1.0295e+03, 0.0000e+00,
        1.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,
        0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,
        0.0000e+00]])
```

My target shape is:

```
y_train_3d.shape
>>> (2918, 4, 1)
```

The first element looks like this:

```
y_train_3d[0]
>>> array([[ 5795.],
       [19494.],
       [24851.],
       [13475.]])
```

So both the shape and the content look the way they are supposed to be.

The 3. model is my LSTM model. My model is as follows:

```
num_sequence = 4

inputs = Input(shape=(num_sequence, 21))
x = LSTM(32, activation='relu', dropout=0.0, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
outputs = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)


model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse', metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError()])

print(model.summary())
```

The summary of the model is:

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================

 input_1 (InputLayer)       [(None, 4, 21)]           0         
                                                                 
 lstm_2 (LSTM)              (None, 4, 32)             6912      
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 4, 1)              33        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 6,945
Trainable params: 6,945
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**My Problem:**
If I use this LSTM and let it run for 500 epochs, first it seems to actually learn and the training error goes down, but at one point after 180 epochs, the training error gets worse again.

```
Epoch 178/500
92/92 - 0s - loss: 67061724.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 8189.1221 - val_loss: 73245328.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 8558.3486 - 488ms/epoch - 5ms/step
Epoch 179/500
92/92 - 1s - loss: 63150060.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 7946.7012 - val_loss: 73750616.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 8587.8184 - 536ms/epoch - 6ms/step
Epoch 180/500
92/92 - 1s - loss: 114693592.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 10709.5098 - val_loss: 149320688.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 12219.6846 - 661ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 181/500
92/92 - 1s - loss: 121518424.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 11023.5391 - val_loss: 125545216.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 11204.6963 - 646ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 182/500
92/92 - 1s - loss: 115984808.0000 - root_mean_squared_error: 10769.6240 - val_loss: 122884320.0000 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 11085.3203 - 690ms/epoch - 8ms/step
```

After 500 epochs I predicted on the training set and got those results:

```
model.predict(X_train_3d)
>>> array([[[22839.49 ],
        [22839.49 ],
        [22839.49 ],
        [22839.49 ]],

       [[26642.746],
        [26642.746],
        [26642.746],
        [26642.746]],

       [[27665.633],
        [27665.633],
        [27665.633],
        [27665.633]],

       ...,

       [[13904.507],
        [13904.507],
        [13904.507],
        [13904.507]],

       [[12234.53 ],
        [12234.53 ],
        [12234.53 ],
        [12234.53 ]],

       [[15874.946],
        [15874.946],
        [15874.946],
        [15874.946]]], dtype=float32)
```

I am quite new to Sequential models and therefore I might miss some concepts to see the error here.
To me everthing looks fine in the sense that the training data has the right shape and the LSTM model gives the correct output shape. Also until the ~epoch 180 the model seems to improve and learn until suddenly it gets worse and it just predicts the same value for each time step.

As you can see I am also not using any regularization here on purpose, since my model does not even seem to be able to fit the training data well and therefore I am guessing this is more of a `high bias` problem and regularization is not helping.

Can someone provide me with some intuition on what is happening here?
Apart from a general intuition, my expectation would be if I use no regularization at all and train for a long enough time, I should be able to at least overfit my training data which should result in

```
model.predict(X_train_3d)
```

being close to my `y_train_3d` e.g., first element

```
>>> array([[ 5795.],
       [19494.],
       [24851.],
       [13475.]])
```

But as we can see, all values are the same and far off e.g., for the first element. I also used the same architecture with a bigger model (2 LSTM layers) and received similar result. Therefore, it does not seem to be a problem that my model is too small and cannot pick up the pattern.

For additional comparision:
My Dense model has `Trainable params: 3,329`
The LSTM has `Trainable params: 6,945`
So, in theory it should have the capability of picking up complex patterns and do well on the training data.

Comment: One basic thing is to normalize inputs and  possibly also outputs since this is regression.

Comment: Thanks. I also tried normalizing my inputs and did this for the other two mentioned models and it did indeed help. For debugging reasons (to easier interpret the values) I did not normalize in the end. The weird behaviour is also with normalizing. As far as I read, it is not necessary to normalize the outputs (in regression at least)

Answer (score 0):

The answer: I would say to much training.
You have a lot more ways of building up your architecture, to create way better models.

Start trying some new models with only 5 to 10 epochs, and see results.
Also in this implementation I would do more units, like 64, on the LSTM since you have a lot of input features.

So in a nutshell: less epochs, different architectures, more units.

Highly recommend this: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to start out with a very simple architecture to get the hang of it. Can you explain what you mean with "more filters"?

Comment: I wrote the answer very fast, and made a bunch of language mistakes. When i said filters I was thinking of units.